# how to fetch data from subcollection of document of firebase firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is my firebase firestore how to fetch data and display in my flutter app
[image]

I need to fetch data from subcollection. for every user there created a separate subcollection. whenever a user login the app should the data of that user

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to fetch all the users in your firebase

```
Future<Object> getUser() async {
  try {
    CollectionReference users =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('userData');
    final snapshot = await users.doc().get();
    final data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return data.entries;
  } catch (e) {
    return 'Error fetching user';
  }
}
```